# errors - PLS-00679: trigger binds not allowed in before/after statement section

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have these errors - PLS-00679: trigger binds not allowed in before/after statement section
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OUT.PUT_LINE' must be declared - but cant locate the problem. 
These are the scripts involved-

```
create or replace trigger hiTk
for insert or update on lending
COMPOUND TRIGGER
--declare
L_Date date;
subtype copy_booksRec is lending%ROWTYPE;
type copied_bks is table of copy_booksRec;
cbks copied_bks := copied_bks();

before each row is 
begin
  cbks.extend;
  cbks(cbks.last).cb_num := :new.cb_num;
  cbks(cbks.last).sb_num := :new.sb_num;
--  cbks.last(i).date_L := :new.date_L;
end before each row;

before statement is
begin 
  for i in cbks.first .. cbks.last loop
    select count(date_L) into L_Date from lending where sb_num = cbks(i).sb_num and date_L = :new.date_L;

    if (Sysdate = :new.date_L) then
      dbms_out.put_line('You can only make ONE LOAN at a time! You have already loaned a book on ' || L_Date);
    else
      cbks.delete;
    end if;
  end loop;
  FORALL i IN cbks.first .. cbks.last
      insert into lending values cbks(i);
    cbks.delete;
  end before statement;
end hiTk;
/
show errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both errors are accurately telling you what is wrong:

1. PLS-00679: trigger binds not allowed in before/after statement section

But you have:

```
before statement is
begin 
  for i in cbks.first .. cbks.last loop
    select count(date_L) into L_Date from lending where sb_num = cbks(i).sb_num 
    and date_L = :new.date_L;
    --           ^^^^ THIS IS A TRIGGER BIND, NOT ALLOWED IN BEFORE STATEMENT
```

1. PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OUT.PUT_LINE' must be declared

There is no supplied package called `DBMS_OUT`, it is called `DBMS_OUTPUT`.